# How can I pass a context.Context via Gin's context?

Tags: go, go-gin, go-context

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to propagate a `context.Context` for the purposes of tracing with OpenTelemetry when using Gin.

I currently have a `gin` handler that calls a function and passes a `*gin.Context`, like so:

```
func (m Handler) doSomething(ginCtx *gin.Context, name string) {
  ctx, span := otel.Tracer("mytracer").Start(ginCtx.Request.Context(), "doSomething")
  defer span.End()
  // ...
}
```

This actually results in incorrect spans, since before `doSomething()` is called, I create a new `context.Context` in the calling function with the parent span information (similar to the snippet above).

In most of my code, I'm passing around a `context.Context`, but figured I could make use of gin's `Context`. Otherwise I have to pass both types of contexts:

```
func (m Handler) doSomething(ctx context.Context, ginCtx *gin.Context, name string) {
  ctx, span := otel.Tracer("mytracer").Start(ctx, "doSomething")
  defer span.End()
  // ...
}
```

This feels wrong since the `Request` stored in the `*gin.Context` is out of sync with what I'm passing around as a parameter via `context.Context`. However, I'm afraid to set the `Request` on the `*gin.Context` with a new `Request` that has the updated `Context` because

1. It's only for this function and I'd have to un-set it (maybe through a `defer()`?)
2. It doesn't seem like it'd be thread-safe (though I assume I'd need to `Copy()` the gin Context in this scenario anyway)

Is the proper way to handle this just `Copy`ing the `*gin.Context` and modifying the Request with the new `context.Context`, then passing the `*gin.Context` around instead of `context.Context`?

I don't know what the implications are of `Copy`ing a `gin.Context` from the text:

> Copy returns a copy of the current context that can be safely used outside the request's scope. This has to be used when the context has to be passed to a goroutine.

Can I still `Abort()` through a copied `*gin.Context`, and is the old one still usable after copying? I just need something that behaves like a stack in the same way that passing `context.Context`s around does, where simply returning from the function "pops" the context off and I'm left with the old one.

Comment: Question: are you injecting a value into the context you're passing around?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not overly familiar with the `gin` package, but I had some similar requirements for `labstack/echo` and I solved it by injecting what I needed into the function this way:

```
type Router struct {
    Inner *gin.Gin
}

func (router *Router) Handle(ctx context.Context, method string, route string, handler(context.Context, *gin.Context) gin.IRoutes {
    return router.Inner.Handle(method, route, func(gCtx *gin.Context) error {
        return handler(ctx, gCtx)
    })
}
```

This works by allowing you to inject the `context.Context` in when you declare the route. So, instead of doing this:

```
g := gin.Default()
g.POST("/some/route", myHandler) // myHandler accepts *gin.Context
```

you can now do:

```
r := Router{Inner: gin.Default()}
r.Handle("POST", "/some/route", myHandlerV2) // myHandlerV2 accepts *gin.Context and context.Context
```

This pattern would also allow you to inject other dependencies such as database connections, loggers, etc.